# Is there a way to INSERT or UPDATE using an Excel file into PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, excel, postgresql, api, flask-restful

I have a PostgreSQL database and I need people with no knowledge of SQL to be able to make insertions or update some catalogs using only Excel. Is it possible to call an API, pass some arguments, and create a "button" on Excel to make these operations on PostgreSQL tables ?

Comment: If you're prepared to write VBA and your users are prepared to install your scripts you can do pretty much anything you like. If the PostgreSQL server is in their local network then you can connect via ODBC or similar to do basic queries.

Comment: Regarding the upload operations, what would be the best structure to create ? 
User needs to add a product to this catalog. Should they write an external .csv file with the data they want and just call an API to read this file and upload it to Postgre? I'm a little confused on how to construct it.

Comment: Yes as stated by @Richard, you can develop VBA procedures embedded in the xls file  and that will be triggred by a button. With VBA you can use the Microsoft ADO middleware to connect to the postgres db and use the ADO recordset to manipulate the data, including triggering a postgres function to insert / update data in the db. See [ADO fundamentals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/ado-fundamentals?view=sql-server-ver16)